# Mailboxer html formattting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mailboxer

How can I allow Mailboxer gem to send HTML formatted messages?

For example, I want the first message user A sends to user B to be pre-formatted with certain text and HTML tags. Currently any kind of markup is escaped..

EDIT: My question is basically how can I "patch" the send_message functionality? Or create a new send_message2 that behaves the way I want?

Comment: Have you tried `.html_safe`? All in all, it is impossible for anyone to help you if you don't post some code of what you've done so far...

Comment: @RubyRacer I don't really know where to start. I updated my question to focus on what im trying to figure out